# How to match a value from a table upto a particular position in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have to write a query to match values in two tables, Table A and Table B , Table A is havingvalues in column XYZ as "91517181","915171812", i want to check if its exist in table B or not , but in table B, the value in column ABC is "9151718", but in another column in table B it is having its match length as "10". Which means it is upto "9151718XXX".
So i have to write a query where value from table A should match with value in table B, because in table B, the value is upto 10 characters.
Kindly help...

Comment: your question is not clear , can you clarify more ? what do you mean value is up to 10 characters?

Comment: It means if in table B, the value in column X is "9151718" and value in column Y is "10", and if we match it with values from table A, as "91517181" and '915171812"  it should match with it, because 10 denotes the beginning and ends positions for the characters to match.                                                          If the value in table B would be "91360" and in column Y the value is  "5"  and if we match it with value in table A which contains "913601" , it should not match , because "91360" are 5 characters and "913601" is 6.

Comment: you want to match the length of characters for the columns ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like this:

```
table a:             table b:
xyz                  x           y
----------           ----------  ---
9151718              9151718      10
91517181             91360         5
913601
```

---

```
select a.xyz, rpad(xyz, b.y, 'x') result, b.x pattern, b.y len
  from a 
  left join b on a.xyz like b.x||'%' and length(a.xyz)<=b.y
```

---

```
xyz         result      pattern     len
----------  ----------  ----------  ---
9151718     9151718xxx  9151718      10
91517181    91517181xx  9151718      10
913601                                      <- not matched
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Stibbons.. Your Query really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that:

`select * from a where 
exists(select 'x' from b where substr(xyz, 1, y) = x)`

x - value in b
y - length in b